# android - BroadcastReceiver not calling OnReceive when sending SMS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm creating an app where part of it will send a message if it meet a certain condition but whenever it is being sent, the receiver does not call onReceive method. I tried all the suggestions from the answered SO questions but nothing helped me fix it. I want to get the report if my SMS is sent with these codes:

BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class SendSMS extends BroadcastReceiver {

public SendSMS() {
    super();
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int resultCode = getResultCode();
    switch (resultCode) {
        case AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK:
            result = "Message sent.";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
            result = "Error. Message not sent.";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
            result = "Error: No service.";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
            result = "Error: Null PDU.";
            break;
        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
            result = "Error: Radio off.";
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Sending text class:

```
public class SMSSender {
private Context context;
private final int MAX_SMS_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 160;
private final String SMS_SENT = "sent";
private final String SMS_DELIVERED = "delivered";


public SMSSender(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}


public void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
    SendSMS brSendSMS = new SendSMS();

    try {
          //##### Also tried all kinds of context ###### //
        PendingIntent piSend = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(SMS_SENT), 0);

        int length = message.length();


        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(brSendSMS, new IntentFilter(SMS_SENT));


        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();       
        smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, piSend, null);



    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Toast.makeText(context, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {
        context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(brSendSMS);
    }
}
```

}

And to test this, I placed it in button clicked method.

```
        SMSSender smsSender = new SMSSender(this);
        smsSender.sendSMS("000000", "TESTING ONLY");
```

What am I doing wrong here? I also learned that it uses my default sms app stating "Not sent. Tap to try again".

Comment: we didnt understand your purpose. Are you sending messages from a device and expecting the receiver to called on same device or different devices?

Comment: @Sush Just updated my question.